# Proof of $\delta^{(n)}(-x) = (-1)^n\delta^{(n)}(x)$ and $ x\delta^{(n)}(x) = -n\delta^{(n-1)}(x)$

Tags: proof-writing, dirac-delta

I need to prove the following identities regarding the Dirac delta function:

> $$\text{1.) }\delta^{(n)}(-x) = (-1)^n\delta^{(n)}(x) \hspace{40pt}\text{2.) } x\delta^{(n)}(x) = -n\delta^{(n-1)}(x)$$

and one hint I'm given is to somehow use this property:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta^{(n)}(x)dx = (-1)^nf^n(0)$$

Any hints on how to go about doing this? I'm particularly at a loss regarding how to apply the given property since none of the given involves $f(x)\delta^{(n)}(x)$ save for the left-hand side of 2.) where $f(x) = x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to prove the first one, because in my opinion it follows right from the definition of changing variables in generalized functions. Let's prove second one.
$$
(x \delta^{(n)}, \, \varphi) = (\delta^{(n)}, \, x \varphi) = (-1)^{n} (\delta, \, (x \varphi)^{(n)}) = (*)
$$

By Leibnitz formula $$(x \varphi)^{(n)} = \sum \binom{n}{m} x^{(m)} \varphi^{(n-m)} = x \varphi^{(n)} + \binom{n}{1} x' \varphi^{(n-1)} = x\varphi^{(n)} + n \varphi^{(n-1)}.$$

Therefore,

$$
(*) = (-1)^{n} (\delta, \, x \varphi^{(n)}) + (-1)^{n} (\delta, \, n \varphi^{(n-1)}) = 0 + (-n \delta^{(n-1)}, \, \varphi).
$$

So,
$$
x\delta^{(n)} = -n \delta^{(n-1)}.
$$

N.B. $(\cdot, \, \cdot)$ is a common notation for generalized functions. If you're not familiar with it, you can treat it as a scalar product in $L_2$:

$$
(f, \, g) = \int f(x) g(x) \, dx
$$

Notice the property $(f', \, g) = - (f, \, g)$ (**integration by parts!**).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm afraid I got a bit lost with some parts. I'm not familiar with the (⋅,⋅) notation, so using the integral notation you prodived, how is it that you got from:


$\int\delta^{(n+1)}(x)x\varphi(x) = (-1)^{n+1}\int\delta(x)(x\varphi(x))^{(n)}$?

I take it that the $(x\varphi(x))^{(n)}$ on the right-hand side means the n-th derivative of $(x\varphi(x))$. If so, why is it that it is only $(n)$ instead of $(n+1)$ like you did with the $\delta(x)$ part?

Comment: You're right, it's $(n +1)$. My mistake. Let me correct it.

PS. $(\cdot, \, \cdot)$ notation emphasizes the fact that $\delta$ is not a proper function, but a continious functional over smooth functions.

Comment: Now everything has to be in order.